# Python - Plotly - Range sliders only work on top figure in vertically stacked graphs

Tags: python, bash, graph, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have managed to get almost exactly what i wanted from this using python for the first time but im stuck with the final piece.

I cannot get the Plotly range slider to effect both figures. I have vertically stacked subplots, figure1 & figure2. stacked into this_figure.

I am writing data to a CSV and reading from there into the below figures.

```
    figure1 = px.line(df,  x = 'time', y = 'temp', title='Temperature')
    figure2 = px.line(df,  x = 'time', y = ['Dosinga','Dosingb'], title='Dosing')

    figure1_traces = []
    figure2_traces = []
    for trace in range(len(figure1["data"])):
        figure1_traces.append(figure1["data"][trace])
    for trace in range(len(figure2["data"])):
        figure2_traces.append(figure2["data"][trace])

    #Create a 1x2 subplot
    this_figure = sp.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, subplot_titles =['Temperature', 'Dosing'])
    this_figure.update_layout(height = 1000, width = 2500, title_text = "Fishtank")

    for traces in figure1_traces:
        this_figure.append_trace(traces, row=1, col=1)
    for traces in figure2_traces:
        this_figure.append_trace(traces, row=2, col=1)

    
    this_figure.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1, label="1D", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=7, label="1W", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1, label="1M", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
    )
    
    #the subplot as shown in the above image
    this_figure.write_html("/home/pi/shared/Graph.html")
```

I have tried adding the range slider to each figure seperatly, as below but for both figures.
I have also tried adding the range slider to only one of the figure at a time.

all of these attempts have caused no issues with the code but the range slider and range selector buttons completely disappear.

```
figure_1.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1, label="1D", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=7, label="1W", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1, label="1M", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a range slider for each plot, add the first as you've done with `this_figure.update_layout( xaxis=dict(` etc, then add the second in the same manner but specifying `xaxis2`.

To ensure you can see everything on the screen and things don't overlay you may have to tweak the `vertical_spacing` when initialising your subplots. For example: `make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, subplot_titles=['Temperature', 'Dosing'], vertical_spacing=0.5)`

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks!! Had to add some vertical spacing as well so thanks for mentioning that off the bat.